# Inno Setup, APP start When windows start

Tags: inno-setup

For Inno Setup,
I would like to create a checkbox Task for MyAPP Auto Start when Windows Start.
My code like below :

And, How to write the codes below - DO_Set_AutoStart_WhenWindowsStart()
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
[Tasks]
Name: "StartMenuEntry" ; Description: "Start my app when Windows starts" ; GroupDescription: "Windows Startup"; MinVersion: 4,4;

[code]

//Do Additional Task - Auto Start when Windows Start 

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
    Index := WizardForm.TasksList.Items.IndexOf('Start my app when Windows starts');
    if Index <> -1 then
    begin
      if WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[Index] then
        MsgBox('First task has been checked.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
        DO_Set_AutoStart_WhenWindowsStart();
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      else
        MsgBox('First task has NOT been checked.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: See also [Option to make application automatically start with Windows when installing using Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40146434/850848).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need to make use of the *[code]* section to add an automatic starting app.

There are different ways to accomplish this, for example

```
[icons]
Name: "{userstartup}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks:StartMenuEntry;
Name: "{commonstartup}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks:StartMenuEntry;
```

The difference between {userstartup} and {commonstartup}, if not obvious, is that {userstartup} affects the startup menu entry for the current user and {commonstartup} affects all the users of the target machine.

---

### Edit

You may also use the registry to start an application. I'm adding this because the OP mentioned in comments the described method doesn't work on windows 8 (because the lack of start menu, which I forgot). I have no windows 8 at hand to test, so it's up to you to test if this works on windows 8 or not.

The [Run keys in the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866) exists since WinXP, so you can configure windows to auto-run a program from the installer adding something like this:

```
[Registry]
;current user only
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MyProgram"; ValueData: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks:AutoRunRegistry;

;any user
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "MyProgram"; ValueData: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks:AutoRunRegistry;
```

Don't miss I'm also changing the `Tasks` parameter in the example to `AutoRunRegistry`.

Comment: You should only use one or the other, not both.  Which you choose should usually depend on what you have `PrivilegesRequired` set to.

Comment: @Miral {commonstartup} requires elevated privileges, but even with it, sometimes you may want to use the {userstartup}, so it depends more on if your program is required to run for any user on that computer. :)

Comment: Thank you so much, jachguate ! However, I need the checkbox for user choose, Can I do the Auto Start with a Checkbox ?

Comment: @jachguate: You may want to do it, but it's still wrong to do so.

Comment: @Miral, sorry, I don't get about what's your comment.

Comment: It seems the method can not works in Win 8 ? There is no starup in Win 8 !!

Comment: @健榮 陳 I'm updating my answer to include the registry option, but I have no windows 8 at hand to test.

Comment: Hi Jachguate, Thanks a lot for your help. I found " Registry for current user only" is useful for WinXP only. If for Win7 and Win8, it must " Registry for all users" . In addition, I found the " Windows Startup" of Win8. There are two, one is C:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\Mircosoft\windows\starMenu\Programs\Startup ; and the other is C:\ProgramData\Mircosoft\windows\StarMenu\Programs\Startup. However, the default {userstartup} and {commonstartup} was not defined for Win8, Can we define another Marco for Win 8 ?

Comment: @健榮 陳 In win7 the current user registry setting works, are you sure about what you say in win8?

Comment: Hi jachguate, you are right. it should be all works. I finally find my problem. Since my Application needs to be run as Administrator, therefore, it fails to auto start. only registry for all user could be worked.

Comment: @jachguate How to add a check box for the users to choose whether they want to add the program to startup or not?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi you can ask your own question if you want, comments are not designed to ask or answer questions.

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation about `AutoRunRegistry` flag. What does it do in that case?

Comment: That's not a flag. It is a "task" the registry actions are bounded to, to allow the user to choose if she want's to run this task or not, just as a example. Read documentation about the task parameter for more information.

Comment: how to add params to the app, should be under the `ValueData` as well? ex.`"{app}\init.exe --help";`

Comment: Yes, you just "write" the command line to be executed to the registry, including parameters if needed.

Comment: Just an update, I got an error `Directive or parameter "Tasks" expression error: Parameter "Tasks" includes an unknown task`, so I tried to remove the syntax, just use `Name: "{commonstartup}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"`, works for me on Win10 with Inno version 6.0.5.

Comment: The answer contains a `StartMenuEntry` task dependencie, because the question have a `[Tasks] Name: "StartMenuEntry"` section. Of course that will work only for the OP and you made well by removing the dependencie if you want the registry entry to always run. If you want it to run depending in the user selection, you should just change the name of the `task` you want to depend on.

Comment: can we add something in the command that whenever application runs on startup that should be on minimize state?

Comment: @Harish sure you can, for example, you can add a parameter to the command line like `/runMinimized`, and you make your application recognize the command line parameter and minimize itself on startup.

Comment: In Windows 10, this works for me:
;current user only
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SomeName!!!"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
;any user
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "SomeName!!!"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"