# Option to make application automatically start with Windows when installing using Inno Setup

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I am using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to make my exe installable. I used its wizard to create setup which is working well.

But I want to make a choice for user to make the application start with startup of Windows. How can I do this?

I just want simple interface for user no manual work for user.

Answer (score 3):

To make an application start when an user logs in, add an entry to the `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry key using an entry in the [`[Registry]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection).

See also

- [Inno Setup, APP start When windows start](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13244181/850848)
- [Inno Setup - how can I make my program run when a user logs in to Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7490249/850848)

Do not use the `[Icons]`, that's a legacy solution.

---

To allow user to select whether to configure the automatic start, associate the `[Registry] entry` with a [task](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection), like:

```
[Tasks]
Name: startup; Description: "Start application when user logs in"

[Registry]
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "MyProgram"; ValueData: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
    Tasks: startup
```

Answer (score -1):

to access write in HKLM section you gotto set the following flags:

```
[Setup]
 PrivilegesRequired=admin
 ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

otherwise use HKCU