# Set the check state of the task to match the current startup state (if upgrading)

Tags: inno-setup, autostart

My software installer allows the user to start the application when the user logs in. It does that like this:

```
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "appname"; ValueData: "{app}\appname.exe"; \
    Tasks: startup
```

It is based on the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40147393/2287576). But the software itself allows the user to modify the start-up state (by programmatically adding/removing the same registry data).

How can I adjust the Inno Setup Script to detect if:

1. It is upgrading and
2. If it is already in the Startup list

I would like the check state of the task to match the current startup state (if upgrading)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What problem are you trying to fix? If you want the installer to validate if the registry data is there, you could read the registry value from the `[Code]` section.